# Excel count unique values from a if values from b are grather than 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns. I want to count the unique values from A if the corresponding value from b is grather than 0

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2 |
| Mary |  |
| John | 2 |
| John |  |
| Sally | 2 |
| Terry | 1 |
| Terry |  |

In the above example the result will be 3 (john + sally + terry).
I am using excel 2016. I saw same example with Unique but this function is not available.
Is there any other way of achieving this without using pivot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this complex formula:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(IF($B$1:$B$7>0,$A$1:$A$7,""))>0,MATCH(IF($B$1:$B$7>0,$A$1:$A$7,""),IF($B$1:$B$7>0,$A$1:$A$7,""),0),""),IF(LEN(IF($B$1:$B$7>0,$A$1:$A$7,""))>0,MATCH(IF($B$1:$B$7>0,$A$1:$A$7,""),IF($B$1:$B$7>0,$A$1:$A$7,""),0),""))>0,1))
```

[image]

To better understand it, I suggest you break it up into it's component parts and examine the results (or use the Formula evaluation tool).

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

Comment: This is not working. It's not giving the expected result

Comment: @chris_b Your sample data show three unique entries and it returns a result of 3.  If your real data is not accurately represented by the sample data, I am not surprised.  Or possibly you did not enter it as an array formula?  Instructions added.

Comment: The proble was that I was not hitting ctrl+shift+enter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365 this could be done like this: `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,B:B>0)))`
You already referenced you do not have this, but if somebody searches this and do have Office 365 this may be helpful.